# How to reference a WCF Web Service via URI/ how to POST to WCF Service via URI?

Tags: .net, wcf, service, web, uri

I am new to creating Web Services and I do not understand exactly how to access my web service.

What I am trying to do is the create a WCF webservice that reads JSON data that is posted to it and deserializes it then does something.

I have create a very simple WCF service with two methods exposed and a uri endpoint created. Though when I go to my uri I get nothing.

I should be able to navigate to 'http:// localhost : 8000/asd/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!' in my browser and that method should return "You said " + s. When I navigate to that with the service running I get nothing.

My question is how do I interface my program? Can I also post to my service via an HTML form then open a IO reader?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Below is my code.

```
namespace WcfService1
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string EchoWithGet(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    string EchoWithPost(string s);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }
    public string EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }
}

class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/asd/"));
        ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WebHttpBinding(), "");

        /*
        ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
        */

        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Updated, I think my issue stems from my config file. What information do I need to add to the config file to be able to consume my web service via the browser?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify 
using below code and check it again.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <services>     
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior"
    name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />       
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JSONEndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>        
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and modify the webvoke with below code

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/EchoWithPost/{s}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

string EchoWithPost(string s);

Comment: you can try by removing below endpoints inside service tag             <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"> </endpoint> <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help but unfortunately neither of these solution fix my problem. I have created my URI correctly and created the endpoint correctly as well? So I should be able to access my service locally? I can use the WCF client and it works fine, I just want to be to access it via a browser, and eventually via a post method. 

Did I create my endpoint correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Also forgive me not know what I am doing butwhy did you add the 'Get' verb to the webInvoke attribute? I thought webGet supported Get, and webInvoke was for other verbs such as POST, PUT, DELETE, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try It in serviceModel section of your Web.config file :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehavior" name="Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJSONP" contract="IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJSONP"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```